# How save data with special symbols in cakephp 2.4.x?

Tags: php, cakephp

I want save some special symbols to save in database using cakephp's query() function.
Sanitize functions of cakephp is not working.

```
$data = Sanitize::escape($this->request->data['Post']['body']);
```

I want save posted data with any symbols typed in database and show it in my view page.
How make it possible? 
//Editted//

For example something like this

> 'Hello ..',I am new to stackoverflow', etc

When I add like this it will not be saving to database. I used save() method also. But no effect..Is it possible to use mysql_real_escape function in cakephp

Comment: Don't use the Sanitize class. There is a good reason its deprecated and will be removed. Just don't :) Save it normally and use h() to secure output in the view. Done. See [this article](http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/10/05/cakephp-security/) for details.

Comment: My previous comment might have been misunderstood: _show what you're doing_ i.e. _add your query call to the question_.

Comment: Thank you AD7six. I got my answer. h() function resulting whatever typed in text fields. h() function help to protect Xss attacks...

Comment: And will do absolutly nothing to protect you from sql injection - which if you're still using query, you are wide open to.

Comment: It is still possible to use `mysql_real_escape_string()` although it is deprecated and you should use `mysqli_*` instead. However, generally speaking the CakePHP inserting wrappers will handle string escaping internally, and modern versions of Cake will of course use parameterised queries with PDO which eliminate the need to escape strings like this anyway. For an example like you posted which doesn't use any special symbols that wouldn't occur in UTF8 encoding normally, there is really no need to *manually* escape them.